# How to remove a background song mixed with another?

Tags: sound-design, editing, music, sound-editing

I have a mp3 file which contains the master song but somehow some other is also playing alongside. Main song is little louder than the background one.

I tried audacity it doesn't show 2 tracks where I can remove one. Is there any way I can extract the original song from that?

I am little new to these softwares, so detailed guidance will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[Like Mark said](https://sound.stackexchange.com/a/46877/14716), you can't.  Mixing audio is literally adding the samples together at each moment in time to produce a single result.  That works whether it's digital numbers, analog voltage, or acoustic air pressure.

So "unmixing" a track is like taking the number 273 and figuring out what two numbers were originally added to get it.  You can't do that.

That's why the recording process itself, and the original source, are so important.  You can't fix everything in post.

Answer (score 0):

No there is nothing you can do. The 'quieter' song will have been mixed in during the original encoding event, possibly in another master WAV file or in another incorrectly routed source into the signal path that was sent to the encoder. There isn't anything you can do to remove it.